# Draw the graph of $f(x)=\min\{\lvert x \rvert-1,\lvert x-1\rvert -1,\vert x-2\rvert -1\}$

Tags: graphing-functions, absolute-value

I have had drawn this answer myself but I want clarification. What I do is:

\begin{cases}
  y = x-2 & \text{for } x\ge 1\\    
     \space \space = -x  & \text{for }x<1   
\end{cases}

\begin{cases}
  y = x-1 & \text{for } x\ge 0\\    
     \space \space = -x-1  & \text{for }x<0   
\end{cases}

\begin{cases}
  y = x-3 & \text{for } x\ge 2\\    
     \space \space = -x+1  & \text{for }x<2   
\end{cases}

Now we see that for $\space x<0, \;y=-x-1$ is the equation.

For $\; x\ge 0$ and $x\le \dfrac{1}{2},$ $y=x-1$ is the equation

For $\, x\ge \dfrac{1}{2},$ but $x<1$, we use $y=-x. $

For $\space x\ge 1 \space \text{and} x<\dfrac{3}{2}$ we have $y=x-2$.

For $\space x>\dfrac{3}{2} \space \text{and} x\le 2,$ we have $y=-x+1$

For $x>2$, we have $y=x-3$

Can anyone draw the graph and verify whether I am on the right track?

Comment: @Gibbs meaning?? Already written there. Draw the graph of f(x)=Minimum(|x|-1,|x-1|-1,|x-2|-1). I have formed the equations. I want to clarify whether they are correct. Second, if anybody cares to draw the graph based on the equations, I can verify my graph with the graph given by the answerer. As my drawing is on paper, I have to clicka picture of the same but many users reject such snapshots. Thats why I wanted the graph directly .

Comment: It is disheartening to see no one pays attention to the questions. I expected some answers. Now I believe you can't complain about me being unclear or putting no effort. Talking tall about this or that regarding petty issues. You people can't see questions where snapshots of answers are given because you are all short sighted isn't it?Sad it is!

Comment: Forget my previous comment. Perhaps edit the question and it will appear in the feed. It should perhaps grab other user's attention.

Comment: @JohnSmith there is nothing to rephrase in the OP as whatever was there in the book, I directly copied the same to you. Sadly there is nothing else to edit here. If the question had been the least dubious regarding its understanding, I would have acquiesced but in this case there is no lack of clarity in the question itself. I have drawn the graph myself but was unsure about it and sadly I am unaware of software which can draw such graphs and yes this was not an assignment question or Homework question.